Help with a tricky table
I teach maths with a colleague and we wish to create a workbook for our students to use. He want's to use Word, I wish to use \LaTeX. He knows the basics of typesetting in \LaTeX so I want to provide him with a template for us to use.
He's sent me a screenshot for the page heading for the start of each section that he's made in Word:  The background grid isn't needed - he had that for alignment only. He is very particular about the table appearance, hence the workaround I've come up with to deal with the different cell widths between the first two and the last row.
My version looks like below, where I've put two versions of the tricky part. The first version, I've manually put in some column widths to make it look more how I would want it. The second version has extra text added to check the text is wrapping in the cells where I need it to, and the correct text in the black cell and the one below that he only told me as I was showing him my first version.
My second version is adjusting the column width to fit the cell{2}{5} and cell{1}{1} and cell{2}{1} as I would like, but I wish to make the 'IB...' text in cell{1}{2} appear in one line, without wrapping as it does in the first version with the manual controls. Similarly I would like the 'Learning...' text in cell{3}{1} not wrap to a second line (though the latter is less important than the 'IB...' text not breaking into multiple lines).
Is it possible to easily prevent these 2 cells (both multicolumn) from splitting/wrapping to 2+ lines? Is it complicated as my workaround has both of these appearing in a 2-column cell?
Thanks in advance for any help. My code is below:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,dvipsnames,table]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\definecolor{HeadingBlue}{RGB}{202,216,239}
\definecolor{HeadingBubbleTextBlue}{RGB}{97,140,206}
\definecolor{HeadingTextBlue}{RGB}{31,53,90}
\definecolor{TableYellow}{RGB}{255,255,84}
\definecolor{TableBrown}{RGB}{195,188,154}
\definecolor{TableBlue}{RGB}{39,31,231}
\definecolor{BorderInnerGrey}{RGB}{192,192,192}
\definecolor{BorderOuterGrey}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[f,r]Q[c,m]Q[c,m,4cm]},
    hspan = default,
    width = 1\columnwidth,
    cell{1}{1} = {bg=HeadingBlue,fg=HeadingTextBlue, font=\Large},
    cell{1}{2} = {bg=HeadingBlue,fg=HeadingTextBlue, font=\bfseries\large},
    cell{1}{3} = {bg=HeadingBlue,fg=HeadingTextBlue, font=\bfseries\large},     
    vline{1} = {1}{-}{white,2pt},
    vline{1} = {1}{-}{black,1pt, abovepos = 0.4, belowpos = 0.4},
    vline{2} = {1}{-}{black,1pt, abovepos = 0.4, belowpos = 0.4},
    vline{2} = {2}{-}{white,2pt},
    vline{2} = {3}{-}{black,1pt, abovepos = 0.4, belowpos = 0.4},
    vline{4} = {1}{-}{black,1pt, abovepos = 0.4, belowpos = 0.4},
    vline{4} = {2}{-}{white,2pt},
    hline{1} = {1}{-}{black,1pt,leftpos = 0.2, rightpos = 0.2}, 
    hline{2} = {1}{-}{black,1pt,leftpos = 0.2, rightpos = 0.2},
    hline{2} = {2}{-}{white,2pt},
    rulesep=0pt,
    }
    {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{comfortaa}\selectfont\textbf{{CLASS NOTES /\\GUIDED PRACTICE}}} & \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline] 
    \filldraw[draw = white, fill = white] (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 1cm) node[color = HeadingBubbleTextBlue,align=center] {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{comfortaa}\selectfont Topic \\ \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{comfortaa}\selectfont 1};
    \end{tikzpicture} & 
    {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{comfortaa}\selectfont\textbf{
Number and Algebra}} \\
\end{tblr}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[c,m]Q[l,m,4cm]Q[l,m,2.5cm]X[l,m]Q[r,m,1.5cm]},
    hspan = minimal,
    width = 1\columnwidth,
    cell{1}{1} = {bg=black,fg=white, font=\bfseries},
    cell{1}{2,3,4,5} = {TableYellow, font=\bfseries\small},
    cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{},
    cell{2}{1} = {bg=TableBlue,fg=white, font=\bfseries},
    cell{2}{2,3,4} = {TableBrown, font=\bfseries},
    cell{2}{5} = {TableBrown},
    cell{3}{1,2,3,4,5} = {bg=TableBlue,fg=white, font=\bfseries\small},
    cell{3}{1} = {c=2}{},
    cell{3}{3} = {c=3}{},
    row{3} = {
            valign = t
        },
    vline{2,4,5} = {1}{-}{abovepos = 0, belowpos = 0},
    vline{1} = {1}{-}{black,1pt,abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
    vline{1} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,abovepos = 0.5, belowpos = 0.5},
    vline{1} = {3}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt},
    vline{6} = {1}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt},
    vline{6} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,abovepos = 0.5, belowpos = 0.5},
    vline{6} = {3}{-}{black,1pt,abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
    hline{1} = {1}{-}{black,1pt},   
    hline{1} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.8, rightpos = 0.8, endpos},
    hline{1} = {3}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.4, rightpos = 0.4, endpos},
    hline{4} = {1}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.4, rightpos = 0.4, endpos},
    hline{4} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.8, rightpos = 0.8, endpos},
    hline{4} = {3}{-}{black,1pt},
    hline{2,3} = {1}{-}{2pt,white,leftpos = -1, rightpos = -1},
    rulesep=0pt,
    }
    CHA & IB Applications and Interpretations SL & & &\\
    1 & Topic 0.1 & & Introduction - Rounding numbers but it may be longer & \textbf{Day:} 1 \\
    Learning Objective CHA-1.A: & & Interpret the rate of change at an instant in terms of average rates of change over intervals containing that instant. & & \\
\end{tblr}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[c,m]Q[l,m]Q[l,m]X[l,m]Q[r,m]},
    hspan = minimal,
    width = 1\columnwidth,
    cell{1}{1} = {bg=black,fg=white, font=\bfseries},
    cell{1}{2,3,4,5} = {TableYellow, font=\bfseries\small},
    cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{},
    cell{2}{1} = {bg=TableBlue,fg=white, font=\bfseries},
    cell{2}{2,3,4} = {TableBrown, font=\bfseries},
    cell{2}{5} = {TableBrown},
    cell{3}{1,2,3,4,5} = {bg=TableBlue,fg=white, font=\bfseries\small},
    cell{3}{1} = {c=2}{},
    cell{3}{3} = {c=3}{},
    row{3} = {
            valign = t
        },
    vline{2,4,5} = {1}{-}{abovepos = 0, belowpos = 0},
    vline{1} = {1}{-}{black,1pt,abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
    vline{1} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,abovepos = 0.5, belowpos = 0.5},
    vline{1} = {3}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt},
    vline{6} = {1}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt},
    vline{6} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,abovepos = 0.5, belowpos = 0.5},
    vline{6} = {3}{-}{black,1pt,abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
    hline{1} = {1}{-}{black,1pt},   
    hline{1} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.8, rightpos = 0.8, endpos},
    hline{1} = {3}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.4, rightpos = 0.4, endpos},
    hline{4} = {1}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.4, rightpos = 0.4, endpos},
    hline{4} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.8, rightpos = 0.8, endpos},
    hline{4} = {3}{-}{black,1pt},
    hline{2,3} = {1}{-}{2pt,white,leftpos = -1, rightpos = -1},
    rulesep=0pt,
    }
    Concepts & IB Applications and Interpretations SL & & &\\%'IB ... SL' text mustn't wrap
    {Approximation \\ \LaTeX} & Topic 0.1 & & Introduction - Rounding numbers but it may be a longer title that should wrap & \textbf{Day:} 1 \\
    Learning Objective CHA-1.A: & & Interpret the rate of change at an instant in terms of average rates of change over intervals containing that instant. This one should wrap & & \\ %Learning Objective text mustn't wrap
\end{tblr}
\end{document}

*edit: Output screenshot added below:


You have two conflicting requirements here: on one hand, you want the cell with "IB Applications and Interpretations SL" in it to act as if hspan=default were given (so it takes its natural width and the second row cells act accordingly), on the other hand, you want the cell with "Interpret the rate ..." in it to use the rules from hspan=minimal. tabularray can't use both in a single table. I'd propose to split it into two tables. The code becomes a bit cumbersome, but it works (moreover, two inner tables do not require column spans at all now.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,dvipsnames,table]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\definecolor{HeadingBlue}{RGB}{202,216,239}
\definecolor{HeadingBubbleTextBlue}{RGB}{97,140,206}
\definecolor{HeadingTextBlue}{RGB}{31,53,90}
\definecolor{TableYellow}{RGB}{255,255,84}
\definecolor{TableBrown}{RGB}{195,188,154}
\definecolor{TableBlue}{RGB}{39,31,231}
\definecolor{BorderInnerGrey}{RGB}{192,192,192}
\definecolor{BorderOuterGrey}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X},
    width=\columnwidth,
    vline{1} = {1}{-}{black,1pt,abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
    vline{1} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,abovepos = 0.5, belowpos = 0.5},
    vline{1} = {3}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt},
    vline{2} = {1}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt},
    vline{2} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,abovepos = 0.5, belowpos = 0.5},
    vline{2} = {3}{-}{black,1pt,abovepos = 1, belowpos = 1},
    hline{1} = {1}{-}{black,1pt},   
    hline{1} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.8, rightpos = 0.8, endpos},
    hline{1} = {3}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.4, rightpos = 0.4, endpos},
    hline{3} = {1}{-}{BorderInnerGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.4, rightpos = 0.4, endpos},
    hline{3} = {2}{-}{BorderOuterGrey,2pt,leftpos = 0.8, rightpos = 0.8, endpos},
    hline{3} = {3}{-}{black,1pt},
    rulesep=0pt,
    rowsep=0pt,
    colsep=0pt,
    }
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={Q[c,m]Q[l,m]X[l,m]Q[r,m]},
      cell{1}{1} = {bg=black,fg=white, font=\bfseries},
      cell{1}{2,3,4} = {TableYellow, font=\bfseries\small},
      cell{2}{1} = {bg=TableBlue,fg=white, font=\bfseries},
      cell{2}{2,3} = {TableBrown, font=\bfseries},
      cell{2}{4} = {TableBrown},
      vline{2,3,4} = {1}{-}{abovepos = 0, belowpos = 0},
      hline{2,3} = {1}{-}{2pt,white,leftpos = -1, rightpos = -1},
      rulesep=0pt,
    }
    Concepts & IB Applications and Interpretations SL & & \\%'IB ... SL' text mustn't wrap
    {Approximation \\ \LaTeX} & Topic 0.1 & Introduction - Rounding numbers but it may be a longer title that should wrap & \textbf{Day:} 1 \\
    \end{tblr}\\
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={Q[c,t]X[l,t]},
      row{1} = {bg=TableBlue,fg=white, font=\bfseries\small},
    }
    Learning Objective CHA-1.A: & Interpret the rate of change at an instant in terms of average rates of change over intervals containing that instant. This one should wrap \\ %Learning Objective text mustn't wrap
    \end{tblr}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}

The result is the following:


Thank you Sergei - that's spot on. I didn't know you could put two tables inside a table. You say 'cumbersome', but I think it's both simple and elegant as it does exactly what I would like it to and is future proof for other content that I might wish to put into the cells. Thanks for your time and solution.
